# Configure Unity for Inherted Interfaces

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am fairly new to Unity, (well, IoC and DI in general), and am having problems configuring it for my use.

I have two interfaces:

```
public interface ISample { ... }
```

and

```
public interface IDerivedSample : ISample { ... }
```

and a number of concreate classes simular to:

```
public class UseSample : IDerivedSample { ... }
```

I am attempting to configure Unity to resolve these when used like this:

```
public class UsesSample
{
    private ISample _sample;

    public UsesSample(ISample sample) 
    {
        _sample = sample;
    }
}
```

My attempts at getting this configured is failing, so I thought I would ask the crowd on how to do so.

**EDIT**

I have already configured the container to find the different versions of the interfaces by name, so the resulting code for resolving UserSample should be simular to:

```
ISample = contianer.Resolve<ISample>("derived");
```

However, it is failing.

Comment: Can you share the error message or otherwise describe how it's failing? A repro of the container configuration would be useful as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The short answer**

```
container.RegisterType<ISample, UseSample>();
```

**The longer answer**

The code above works if you only register *one* mapping from `ISample` to a concrete class. As I read your question, you have *many* implementations of `ISample`, in which case **ambiquity** arises because the `UsesSample` provides no hint at how to pick a proper `ISample` instance.

There are several ways out of such a conundrum. Some are specific to the DI Container (in this case Unity) while others solve the issue by creating a less ambiguous API design.

You may, for example, use an [Abstract Factory to select a dependency based on a run-time value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943576/is-there-a-pattern-for-initializing-objects-created-wth-a-di-container/1945023#1945023).