# WCF service with multiple implementations of dependency

Tags: wcf, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have a WCF service that will be called from a various clients.

Internally the WCF service uses an ISomething. There are multiple implementations of this interface and I need some clients to use one implementation and other clients to use a different implementation.

In addition, I am using Unity and an IoC container. I would typically set up a custom factory to allow the wcf service itself to be resolved along with its dependency graph, but if I have multiple implementations of a dependency, I do not think I can go with this approach and would have to resort to resolving the ISomething within the service (effectively using Unity as a service locator) which is not ideal.

So I need to work out

(1) how to specify which implementation of ISomething a client needs (eg. use a header, pass implementation string in each method, host multiple endpoints etc.)

(2) how Unity fits in?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to write a Decorator that performs the selection for you:

```
public class RoutingSomething : ISomething
{
    private readonly ISomeContext ctx;
    private readonly ISomething s1;
    private readonly ISomething s2;
    private readonly ISomething s3;

    public RoutingSomething(ISomeContext ctx)
    {
        this.ctx = ctx;

        // An even better design would be to inject these too
        this.s1 = new BarSomething();
        this.s2 = new BazSomething();
        this.s3 = new QuxSomething();
    }

    // Assuming ISomething has a Foo method:
    public void Foo()
    {
        if(this.ctx.Bar())
        {
            this.s1.Foo();
            return;
        }
        if(this.ctx.Baz())
        {
            this.s2.Foo();
            return;
        }
        if(this.ctx.Qux())
        {
            this.s3.Foo();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

You could generalize this so that ISomeContext is simply an Abstract Factory of ISomething. This then begins to turn into the [general solution to varying dependencies based on run-time context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943576/is-there-a-pattern-for-initializing-objects-created-wth-a-di-container/1945023#1945023).

You can now register RoutingSomething in Unity in addition to your other components. When the container resolves the service, it'll inject an instance of RoutingSomething into it.

Comment: That is pretty nifty but I still need for the service to know which implementation the CLIENT wants to use. How do I pass this information so that it can be accessed early enough to be available when I resolve the service?

Comment: Is the service protected by any sort of authentication? If it is, you might be able to use the authenticated principal as a key to select the correct service. Otherwise, a custom header sounds like a reasonable option.