# Locating dependencies (strategies, repositories etc) depending on subclass type

Tags: design-patterns

Imagine I have the following inheritance structure:

```
AnimalsNamespace.Animal
CatsNamespace.Cat : Animal
DogsNamespace.Dog : Animal
```

In my application classes, I find myself faced with the following type of code a lot:

```
void Feed(Animal animal)
{
    if (animal is Cat)
    {
         KernelContainer.Get<ICatFeedingStrategy>().Feed((Cat)animal);
    }
    else if (animal is Dog)
    {
         KernelContainer.Get<IDogFeedingStrategy>().Feed((Dog)animal);
    }
}
```

This is fine for a while but after I have heaps of these if statements lying around. I then also start getting problems with NHibernate proxies behaving strangely when you request their type etc and things get in a mess.

I could build a Factory class, but I end up with a whole heap of complexity, as just to feed the cat I have to have: ICatFeedingStrategy, ConcreteCatFeedingStrategy, IAnimalFeedingStrategyFactory, ConcreteAnimalFeedingStrategyFactory... (plus often an abstract base class like AnimalFeedingStrategyBase).

Is there a pattern that can help manage these inheritance structures more efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are programming against concrete classes where you should really be **programming against interfaces**.

The example above might be addressed by [using an Abstract Factory to resolve dependencies based on run-time information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943576/is-there-a-pattern-for-initializing-objects-created-via-a-di-container/1945023#1945023). Now the Feed method might look like this:

```
void Feed(Animal animal)
{
    var strategy = this.factory.GetFeedingStrategy(animal);
    strategy.Feed(animal);
}
```

Where the `factory` is an injected IFeedingStrategyFactory.

Another option, when you have a *finite* list of *known* subtypes, is to use the [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Comment: On the contrary, my example is filled with interfaces. Also I mentioned factories in in the fourth paragraph.

Comment: Abstract Factory doesn't eliminate the usage of multiple `if`-s

Comment: @yegor256: But it moves the code away from a place wheres multiple if's is worse.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a [chain of responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) may help here. First, every "feeder" registers itself in the chain. Then, `feed()` calls the first "feeder" from the chain. Every feeder knows how to feed its own subclass. Still you have many `if`-s, but they are closely coupled with their related sub-classes.