# How to handle a list of views with IOC

Tags: model-view-controller, inversion-of-control

If I have a collection which contains a list of models and want to create corresponding views for each model, what is the best way to do this using IOC (inversion of control)?

I see two ways:

1. Use a factory pattern.  I would only pass in my model collection and build views as I need them with a factory that is passed in via IOC.
2. Create a another class which would have a list of all the views I need, pre-built by the IOC.  Then I just pick the view I want from the list.

Which way do you think is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can build the Views in advance the best solution might be to simply inject a list (`IEnumerable`) of all the Views into each consumer and perhaps use the [Specification Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern) to select the appropriate View from that list.

If, on the other hand, you need run-time values before you can instantiate each View, [a Factory is the correct solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943576/is-there-a-pattern-for-initializing-objects-created-via-a-di-container/1945023#1945023).