# Implementing the generic repository and unit of work patterns

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject, unit-of-work

I am trying to implement the generic repository and unit of work patterns according to this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application). In addition to the patterns I have also used Ninject to do dependency injection for my web app.

The specific bindings I used are here:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind(typeof(IGenericRepository<>))
          .To(typeof(GenericRepository<>)).InSingletonScope();
    kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>()
          .To<UnitOfWork>();
}
```

However according to the tutorial, I need to pass the `DbContext` to each repository property in my `UnitOfWork` class so that all repository will share only one `DbContext` instance like here:

```
public GenericRepository<Course> CourseRepository
{
    get
    {
        if (this.courseRepository == null)
        {
            this.courseRepository = new GenericRepository<Course>(context);
        }
        return courseRepository;
    }
}
```

The question is how can I pass the `DbContext` instance (residing in the `UnitOfWork` class) to the `GenericRepository` constructor whenever an instance of `GenericRepository` is injected by Ninject? I know about the `WithConstructorArgument` method but I cannot use it in my `kernel.Bind` calls because I will not have access to the `DbContext` instances at that time.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO your problem is not a dependency injection resolution problem, but a instance dependency when creating the GenericRepository object (you need an specific instance of the dbcontext that depends of the UnityOfWork class that is resolving the IGenericRepository)

Therefore, I would recommend you to use a factory in order to create your IGenericRepository instances.

You can find some further details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943576/is-there-a-pattern-for-initializing-objects-created-via-a-di-container)

Comment: does that mean I have to bind `IGenericRepository` to a `RepositoryFactory` and let the factory decide which concrete repository to create?