# Ninject InSingletonScope Creating multiple instances

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, singleton, ninject

I have a very simple test project where I try tell ninject that my ILoader instance should be a singleton. No matter what I do it creates multiple instances of it.

Simple interface.

```
public interface ILoader
{
    IEnumerable<int> Get();
}
```

Implementation for test purpose

```
public class TestLoader : ILoader
{
    private IEnumerable<int> _Datasource;

    public void Set(IEnumerable<int> enumerable)
    {
        _Datasource = enumerable;
    }
    public IEnumerable<int> Get()
    {
        return _Datasource;
    }
}
```

Class that depends on it

```
public class TestClass
{
    private ILoader _loader;
    public TestClass(ILoader loader)
    {
        _loader = loader;
    }

    public void Init()
    {
        foreach (var i in _loader.Get())
            Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

Module

```
public class TestModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<ILoader>().To<TestLoader>();
        Bind<TestLoader>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
    }
}
```

And run it.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel(new TestModule());

        var ds = new List<int> { 1, 2 };
        kernel.Get<TestLoader>().Set(ds);

        var tc = kernel.Get<TestClass>();
        tc.Init();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Here I want to preload my loader with testdata and the ninject should inject that very same loader into my TestClass. However it creates a new instance which is not really the desired behaviour.

I guess there are ways to work around this. But then what is the purpose of InSingletonScope? Shouldnt I be able to tell ninject that I want one and only one instance of ILoader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having the `Set` method, you should use constructor injection (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33838048/c-sharp-dependency-injection-side-effect-two-step-initialization-anti-pattern/)) like this:

```
public class TestLoader : ILoader
{
    private IEnumerable<int> _Datasource;

    public TestLoader(IEnumerable<int> enumerable)
    {
        _Datasource = enumerable;
    }
    public IEnumerable<int> Get()
    {
        return _Datasource;
    }
}
```

And then here is how you would register it and resolve it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();

    var ds = new List<int> { 1, 2 };

    kernel
        .Bind<ILoader>()
        .To<TestLoader>()
        .InSingletonScope()
        .WithConstructorArgument("enumerable", ds);

    var tc1 = kernel.Get<TestClass>();
    var tc2 = kernel.Get<TestClass>();
    tc1.Init();
    tc2.Init();

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

In this example, the two instance of `TestClass` will get the same instance of `TestLoader` injected into them.

If for some reason you don't want to use constructor injection and you want to keep the `Set` method, you can do this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();

    var ds = new List<int> { 1, 2 };

    kernel
        .Bind<ILoader>()
        .To<TestLoader>()
        .InSingletonScope();


    ((TestLoader)kernel.Get<ILoader>()).Set(ds);

    var tc1 = kernel.Get<TestClass>();
    var tc2 = kernel.Get<TestClass>();
    tc1.Init();
    tc2.Init();

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: The test is not really to load the datasource. It was just there to repsent some call I would like to do on my class before or after it has been injected. But it seems that if i do kernel Get on interface and then cast to my class it indeed returns a single instance. Why does it create a new instance if i Get on the class instead of the interface? Is this really the intended behaviour? Nevertheless your last example is what im trying to do here. Thanks