# Benefit of Factory over Direct Dependency Injection

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container, factory

I came across this piece of code:

```
public class SomeServiceFactory : ISomeServiceFactory
{
    private IUnityContainer container;

    public SomeServiceFactory(IUnityContainer unityContainer)
    {
        this.container = unityContainer;
    }

    public virtual ISomeService GetSomeService()
    {
        return this.container.Resolve<ISomeService>();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to understand how this pattern is more useful then simply having the consumer of this factory simply be injected with `ISomeService` directly? Thus, become a consumer of the service itself, rather than the factory. What does this additional layer of indirection achieve, as implemented here?

I understand that if the creation of `ISomeService` needed more intricate logic, not achievable by `container.Resolve`, then definitely a factory would have been required.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. Without contextual information, it's difficult to defend such a degenerate Abstract Factory.

Sometimes, the reason for this may be that the programmer writing the consumer of this factory *knew* that the `ISomeService` implementation had to be created anew for each use; perhaps that particular implementation wasn't thread-safe.

Furthermore, `ISomeService` might derive from `IDisposable`, and perhaps the client does something like this:

```
using (var svc = this.factory.GetSomeService())
{
    // use svc here...
}
```

This would cause `svc` to be properly disposed of after use.

**All of the above are leaky abstractions,** but common nonetheless.

A better approach to deal with such lifetime and resource management issues is either via a [Decoraptor](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/08/24/decoraptor) or the [Register Resolve Release pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/09/29/TheRegisterResolveReleasepattern).

This, however, could still require you to have a class like `SomeServiceFactory`, but then [it'd be an infrastructure component](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/12/24/placement-of-abstract-factories), for example supporting a Decoraptor.

---

Do note, however, that this particular Abstract Factory is degenerate because it takes no method arguments. An Abstract Factory with one or more method arguments, on the other hand, is a [common solution to the problem of creating a polymorphic service based on a run-time value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1945023/126014).