# How to configure services based on request in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

In ASP.NET Core we can register all dependencies during start up, which executed when application starts. Then registered dependencies will be injected in controller constructor.

```
public class ReportController
{
    private IReportFactory _reportFactory;

    public ReportController(IReportFactory reportFactory)
    {
        _reportFactory = reportFactory;
    }

    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        vart report = _reportFactory.Create();
        return Ok(report);
    }
}
```

Now I want to inject different implementations of `IReportFactory` based on data in current request (User authorization level or some value in the querystring passed with an request).

Question: is there any built-in abstraction(middleware) in ASP.NET Core where we can register another implementation of interface?

What is the possible approach for this if there no built-in features?

**Update**
`IReportFactory` interface was used as a simple example. Actually I have bunch of low level interfaces injected in different places. And now I want that different implementation of those low level interfaces will be injected based on request data.

```
public class OrderController
{
    private IOrderService _orderService;

    public OrderController(IOrderService orderService)
    {
        _orderService = orderService;
    }

    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        var order = _orderService.Create();
        return Ok(order);
    }
}    

 public class OrderService
 {
    private OrderBuilder _orderBuilder;
    private IShippingService _shippingService; // This now have many different implementations

    public OrderService(
        OrderBuilder _orderBuilder,
        IShippingService _shippingService)
    {
        _orderService = orderService;
        _shippingService = shippingService;
    }

    public Order Create()
    {
        var order = _orderBuilder.Build();
        var order.ShippingInfo = _shippingService.Ship();
        return order;
    }
 }
```

Because we know which implementation we need to use on entry point of our application (I think controller action can be considered as entry point of application), we want inject correct implementation already there - no changes required in already existed design.

Comment: You already have factory. Use the factory method `Create` with parameter to retrieve specific instances. If you need to have different factories of factory(why?) then you could use abstract factory pattern.

Comment: You can register multiple implementations of the same interface, you'll get an `IEnumerable<IInterface>` injected.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No, you can't. The `IServiceCollection` is populated during application startup and built before `Configure` method is called. After that (container being built), the registrations can't be changed anymore.

You can however implement an abstract factory, be it as factory method or as an interface/class.

```
// Its required to register the IHttpContextAccessor first
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
services.AddScoped<IReportService>(provider => {
    var httpContext = provider.GetRequired<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext;

    if(httpContext.User.IsAuthorized) 
    {
        return new AuthorizedUserReportService(...);
        // or resolve it provider.GetService<AuthorizedUserReportService>()
    }

    return new AnonymousUserReportService(...);
    // or resolve it provider.GetService<AnonymousUserReportService>()
});
```

Alternatively use an [abstract factory class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943576/is-there-a-pattern-for-initializing-objects-created-via-a-di-container/1945023#1945023)

Comment: In case created `AuthorizedUserReportService ` implements `IDisposed`, will ASP.NET Core dispose it automatically when exit the scope or it should be done manually(how?)?

Comment: It should work, but can only say once looking at the code.  But I am on the way to work now

Comment: Yea it should dispose. Its a factory method after all, it only tells how its instantiated, nothing about its lifetime (thats what the registration method does, `AddScoped`/`AddTransient`/`AddSingleton`)

Comment: Some DI frameworks can do registration after building the Service Provider. Then you can register new dependencies in a middleware. For example, DryIoC can do that. That requires significant change for an existing project, though.

Comment: just to note: it's more clear to use services.AddHttpContextAccessor(); extension method instead of services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid you can not directly acheive the goal via simple dependency injection , as the the dependency injection configured at Startup stage , in other words ,  all services and implementions has been configured before a request comming .

However , you can inject a Create Service delegate so that can we create the required service implemention instance in runtime .

For instance , if we have a `IReportFactory` Interface and two implementions as blew :

```
public interface IReportFactory
{
    object Create();
}

public class ReportFactory1 : IReportFactory
{
    public object Create()
    {
        return new { F = 1, };
    }
}
public class ReportFactory2 : IReportFactory {
    public object Create()
    {
        return new { F = 2, }; 
    }
}
```

As we want to get the required implemention in future , we need to register the Implementions first .

```
services.AddScoped<ReportFactory1>();
services.AddScoped<ReportFactory2>();
```

and here's where the magic happens :

1. We don't register a `IReportFactory`
2. We just add a `Func<HttpContext,IReportFactory>` instead , which is a `CreateReportFactoryDelegate`

   public delegate IReportFactory CreateReportFactoryDelegate(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context);

We need add the CreateReportFactoryDelegate to servies too.

```
services.AddScoped<CreateReportFactoryDelegate>(sp => {
    // return the required implemention service by the context;
    return context => {
        // now we have the http context ,
        // we can decide which factory implemention should be returned;
        // ...
        if (context.Request.Path.ToString().Contains("factory1")) {
            return sp.GetRequiredService<ReportFactory1>();
        }
        return sp.GetRequiredService<ReportFactory2>();
    };
});
```

Now , we can inject a `CreateReportFactoryDelegate` into controller :

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private CreateReportFactoryDelegate _createReportFactoryDelegate;

    public HomeController(CreateReportFactoryDelegate createDelegate) {
        this._createReportFactoryDelegate = createDelegate;
        // ...
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> CacheGetOrCreateAsync() {

        IReportFactory reportFactory = this._createReportFactoryDelegate(this.HttpContext);
        var x=reportFactory.Create();

        // ...
        return View("Cache", cacheEntry);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @JohanP comment about using `IEnumerable`

```cs
//Program.cs
//get the builder
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

//register each type
builder.Services.AddScoped<IReport,Report1>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IReport,Report2>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IReport,Report3>();

//register the factory class
builder.Services.AddScoped<IReportFactory,ReportFactory>();
```

```cs
    //IReport Interface
    public interface IReport
    {
        string ReportType{ get; set; }
    }
```

```cs
//ReportFactory.cs
    public class ReportFactory : IReportFactory
    {
        private IEnumerable<IReport> _handlers;
        
       //ctor
        public ReportFactory(IEnumerable<IReport> handlers) 
            => _handlers = handlers;
        
        internal IReport? Creat(string reportType) =>
            _handlers.Where(h => h.ReportType== reportType).First();
    }
```

```cs
//Controller
public class ReportController
{
    private IReportFactory _reportFactory;

    public ReportController(IReportFactory reportFactory)
    {
        _reportFactory = reportFactory;
    }

//modify to your project needs
    public IActionResult Get([FromBody] string reportType)
    {
      if (HttpContext.User.IsAuthorized)
         {
           var report = _reportFactory.Create(reportType);
           return Ok(report);
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by using the HttpContextAccessor in Startup.cs

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddScoped<IYourService>(provider =>
            {
                var contextAccessor = provider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
                var httpContext = contextAccessor.HttpContext;
                
                var contextVariable = httpContext. ...
                
                // Return implementation of IYourService that corresponds to your contextVariable

              
            });
```