# How to dynamically change connection string ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, connection-string

I'm developing an application that relies on ASP.NET C# for the back-end. I'm trying to change the connection string on the controller depending on what's coming from the request.

Example:

POST 1: access to server 10.126.0.1 db: db_manager

POST 2: access to server 10.126.0.2 db: bd2_manager

The ip and db are supposed to be input to the request and change it accordingly.

I'm currently defining the connection string in the `Startup.cs` (`ConfigureServices` method) file like this:

```
 string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("connection");

            services.AddSingleton<INHibernateSessionFactory>(provider => new NHibernateSessionFactory(connectionString));
            services.AddScoped(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<INHibernateSessionFactory>().OpenSession());
            services.AddScoped<IDataContext, DataContext>();
```

I'd like to know how can I define and change the `connectionString` dynamically for the duration of the request, instead of statically in the startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the settings based on the http request in `ConfigureServices`. Instead you should implement an abstract factory. A full response with example you may find here:
[How to configure services based on request in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51626224/how-to-configure-services-based-on-request-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: Thanks for your help!